Behavior of clustered SEs for cross-level interaction with a 0 cell in fixest
I am using fixest in R for fixed effects logistic regression with clustered SEs. I am not able to share my data but hope I can explain the question well. I have 11 clusters with between 29 and 493 observations per cluster, which are divided between baseline and follow-up time points (called time).
I estimated a cross-level interaction between time and a cluster-level factor variable with 4 levels (called group), so that there are 3 interaction terms. For the second level of group, all outcome values are the same at follow-up. I noticed that for the corresponding interaction term with time, the SE is small when clustering is used, with a very small p-value.
m2 = feglm(y ~ time * L2var | group, data = set1, family = "binomial")
summary(m2)

> summary(m2)
GLM estimation, family = binomial, Dep. Var.: y
Observations: 1,497
Fixed-effects: Site: 11
Standard-errors: Clustered (group) 
                                         Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)    
timeFollow-up                            1.373515   0.342168  4.014151 0.00005966 ***
timeFollow-up:group1                     0.743281   0.778241  0.955078 0.33953814    
timeFollow-up:group2                     14.310706   0.342168 41.823604  < 2.2e-16 ***
timeFollow-up:group3                     0.165190   0.561198  0.294353 0.76848817    
... 3 variables were removed because of collinearity (group1, group2 and group3)
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Log-Likelihood:  -770.6   Adj. Pseudo R2: 0.115961
           BIC: 1,650.8     Squared Cor.: 0.138072

If I remove the clustering by specifying vcov = "iid", the SE and p-value are large, which is what I am used to seeing when there is a 0 cell.
> summary(m2, vcov = "iid")
GLM estimation, family = binomial, Dep. Var.: y
Observations: 1,497
Fixed-effects: Site: 11
Standard-errors: IID 
                                         Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)    
timeFollow-up                            1.373515   0.168833 8.135366 4.1070e-16 ***
timeFollow-up:group1                     0.743281   0.784142 0.947891 3.4318e-01    
timeFollow-up:group2                     14.310706 359.444491 0.039813 9.6824e-01    
timeFollow-up:group3                     0.165190   0.320735 0.515036 6.0653e-01    
... 3 variables were removed because of collinearity (group1, group2 and group3)
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Log-Likelihood:  -770.6   Adj. Pseudo R2: 0.115961
           BIC: 1,650.8     Squared Cor.: 0.138072

My question is: is the small SE and p-value seen with clustered SEs expected, or am I doing something wrong? If it is expected, could someone please provide an intuitive explanation? Thank you!
